# Rake assets precompile error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, asset-pipeline

```
1x-193-157-255-5:HelseBackEnd ola$ rake assets:precompile
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby /usr/bin/rake       assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
rake aborted!
syntax error on line 11, col 0: `--- '

Tasks: TOP => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/...]

Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
1x-193-157-255-5:HelseBackEnd ola$ rake assets:precompile --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby /usr/bin/rake     assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment 
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
syntax error on line 11, col 0: `--- '
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:133:in  `load'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:133:in `load'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:144:in `load_file'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:143:in `open'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:143:in `load_file'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:42
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `run_initializers'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `send'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
 /Users/ola/Documents/Coding/HelseBackEnd/config/environment.rb:5
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:292:in `initialize_tasks'
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `execute'
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:93
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33
 /usr/bin/rake:19:in `load'
 /usr/bin/rake:19
Tasks: TOP => environment
 rake aborted!
 Command failed with status (1): [/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/...]
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:53:in    `create_shell_runner'
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:39:in `sh'
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:80:in `ruby'
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:39:in `ruby'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:12:in `ruby_rake_task'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:21:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `top_level'
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33
/usr/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:19
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
1x-193-157-255-5:HelseBackEnd ola$
```

Is this a problem with my code, or could it be deeper in the core? I can't figure out which file the 11th line is having a problem running.

Comment: ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [universal-darwin11.0]

Comment: @olovholm did you ever resolve your issue?